# Dropzone integration in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I am facing a problem in integrating dropzone.js in my project.I 've used ajax function to upload the images and return the values. But i am getting an 302 error and csrf error. why is it so? How to solve this issue?

My code view page

```
<form method="POST" action="{{lurl('post-events')}}"  enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <label>event title*</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="give it a short distinct name">
  <div class="image_drop">
    <!--<img src="images/upload-files-here.png" pagespeed_url_hash="19921898" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);"/>
                -->
    <div class="dropzone" id="mydropzone" name="mydropzone">
    </div>
    <p>we recommend usung at least a 2160x1080px(2:1ratio) image thats no
                larger than 10MB learn more.</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have used jquery to call the ajax.

```
$("#mydropzone").dropzone({ url: "event-image" });
```

Route.php

```
Route::post('event-image','HomeController@getImage1');
```

controller function

```
public function getImage1() {
  $input = Input::all();
  $rules = array(
    'file' => 'image|max:3000',
  );

  $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

  if ($validation->fails()) {
    return Response::make($validation->errors->first(), 400);
  }

  $file = Input::file('file');
  $extension = File::extension($file['name']);
  $directory = public_path().'/uploads/pictures/events';
  $filename = sha1(time().time()).".{$extension}";

  $upload_success = Input::upload('file', $directory, $filename);

  if( $upload_success ) {
    return Response::json('success', 200);
  } else {
    return Response::json('error', 400);
  }
}
```

In my console i get this error

```
POST http://localhost/Classified/en/event-image  302 Found  
GET http://localhost/Classified/en/events?error=CsrfToken
```

Comment: 302 means Permanent Redirect it means your route is redirect to other page

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a standard web route, laravel will enforce cross site request forgery security, meaning every request needs to have a token to basically authenticate that the signed in user is actually you.

From https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

`$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});`

This will set the csrf-token value (that is automatically passed with every request in laravel) to the x-csrf-token header, and allow your request to have matching tokens.

You can also disable CSRF tokens or use an API route instead, but I don't recommend it due to security flaws so I will not be telling you how to do it this way.

Edit: If you are actually executing the call with all the form data, you can simply add

`{{ csrf_field() }}`

to the form and it should work as expected as well.

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer

just changed the ajax as

```
$("#mydropzone").dropzone({ 

        url: "event-image",
        addRemoveLinks : true,
        maxFilesize: 3,
        sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
            // Pass token. You can use the same method to pass any other values as well such as a id to associate the image with for example.
            formData.append("_token", $('[name=_token').val()); // Laravel expect the token post value to be named _token by default
        }

        });
```